# Destination Port on Internal TCP Load Balancer - Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, internal-load-balancer, google-cloud-load-balancer, gcp-load-balancer

I'm trying to configure an internal Load Balancer on Google Cloud but I'm not able to set a destination port different from the source one.

If I try to create an internal LB from the GCP wizard I cannot see any place in order to set the destination port.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The TCP/UDP load balancing isn't a proxy, it performs port forwarding. It's explained into [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal#forwarding_rule)

> A forwarding rule specifies the protocol and ports on which the load balancer accepts traffic. Because internal TCP/UDP load balancers are not proxies, they pass traffic to backends on the same protocol and port.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a gcp component that act like a reverse proxy?

Comment: You have the HTTP load balancer that allow you to forward the HTTP request to a specific port in your backend. But it's HTTP (layer 7), not TCP (layer 4). There is no TCP (layer 4) reverse proxy product on GCP. Ops in my previous company set up by themselves a reverse proxy on a micro compute engine ($5 per month). It was enough for doing "nothing", but you have to set it up, to manage it, to ensure the high availability by yourselves...